# Identifying a movie about a fast-growing tentacle-plant monster stopped by blood

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify a movie I saw around 2010, but forgot the name of.

Here's what I remember of the movie:

- There is a military base with a sealed sub-level.
- Inside that, there is a room with a body held in a sealed container. The container may look like a bath tub. It is also (if memory serves) full of some sort of preservative liquid.
- When the container is opened, tentacle-like plant growth erupts from the chest of the dead body
- The growth is extremely fast, and spreads in all directions
- It quickly overwhelms the base, and spreads underground towards neighboring towns
- The only thing that repels the growth is the blood of the protagonist
- This is because the dead body in the tub belonged to a family member of his, who worked in the military and created this monster partly with his own cells - so his (and thus, the progatonist's) blood is not recognized as foreign by the growth creature, and thus not digested by it
- The progatonist and his girlfriend (?) coat themselves in his blood, then travel back to the military base to infuse the blood into the creature's "growth nexus" - the spot on the dead body's chest where the growth originated when the container was unsealed
- this kills the creature

I think I may have seen this movie on the syfy/sci-fi channel. Even if not, I'm pretty sure it was somewhere on cable TV. I don't remember much else about the movie, and I've never been able to find it since.

Can anyone help me identify the name of it?

I have tried searching phrases like "growth nexus monster movie" but had no luck.

Comment: This sounds almost like [Evolution(2001)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_(film)) but blood is not the poison

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232473/movie-about-a-creature-that-feeds-on-energy (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 8):

[Living Hell (2008)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_Hell_%28film%29) also known as Organizm (DVD title).

From Wikipedia:

> [H]is mother once worked at the base and warned him that something terrible was stored there, in "Sublevel 3, Vault 12." [...] Inside is a sealed tank [...]. They discover a man's corpse with evidence of disease inside, but when Carrie attempts to biopsy the infected tissue, the infection comes alive in the form of giant, rapidly-growing plantlike roots. Struss is immediately killed when he tries to bolt the tank closed, and the organism grows out of the room in moments. [...] Frank is infected by a sample given to Carrie by an elderly resident, but the organism dies within his body; he realizes that his blood possesses antibodies that can kill the organism due to his heritage. [...] Frank covers Carrie in his blood for protection and they fly in a stolen helicopter back to Fort Lambert so they can kill the organism.