# Movie about a creature that feeds on energy

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

It's a movie about a creature that feeds on any kind of energy. Not only is it immune to bullets, but they also make it bigger. I think it looks like a cloud and may have tentacles. It sort of infests the areas that it reaches.

I remember people in the streets being pulled by its tentacles when one man finds out his blood is sort of poisonous to it. So he and someone else team up to go to where it all started and kill the creature by pouring lots of blood on its center.

As to the release date, I think it's somewhere between 2000 and 2010, maybe late 90s.

Comment: That's a good start. Can we have you go to https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and see if that helps you elicit further details for your question?

Comment: You mighty also want to [register your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161) just so you don't lose access to it in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it could be '[Living Hell](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0479201/)' from 2008; TV release then on DVD, not in the cinema.

> a creature that feeds on any kind of energy

Yes; it can use heat or light to grow (from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_Hell_(film)) summary).

> Not only is it immune to bullets, but they also make it bigger.

Seen in the trailer, as it's shot it moves faster towards the soldier.

> looks like a cloud and may have tentacles

Possibly; I can't see the core in the trailer, but it extends with tendrils.

> one man finds out his blood is sort of poisonous to it.

Yes; he was involved in creating the creature and his blood has antibodies to it.

Comment: Thanks! That's the movie!